# Using jQuery how do I open a larger picture in a target div upon clicking on its thumbnail?

Tags: jquery, image, html, thumbnails

I have got a div that is a target:

```
<div id="rightbox"></div>
```

I have thumbnail images organized by groups:

```
<img src="group1/thumb/01.png" width="160" height="97" class="imgtopleft" />
<img src="group1/thumb/02.png" width="160" height="97" class="imgtopright" />
<img src="group2/thumb/01.png" width="160" height="97" class="imgbottomleft" />
<img src="group2/thumb/02.png" width="160" height="97" class="imgbottomright" />
```

And I have larger images corresponding to each of the thumbs:

```
<img src="group1/large/01.png" width="560" height="297" class="largeimage" />
<img src="group1/large/02.png" width="560" height="297" class="largeimage" />
<img src="group2/large/01.png" width="560" height="297" class="largeimage" />
<img src="group2/large/02.png" width="560" height="297" class="largeimage" />
```

**I want to know if it is possible to show each of the larger images when the corresponding thumbnail is clicked in the target div (with id="rightbox"), by using a function?**

NOTE: I have about 10 groups of thumbnails with corresponding larger images and each is in a specific folder.  I can put all the images within the same directory and using different naming conventions such as image01_thumb.jpg and image01_large.jpg, but the bottom line is I would like to be able to open each of the thumbs in the target div.

I have looked all over for this and have not found this exact question answered yet.

All suggestions and help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

On the assumption that the large images are already present in the `#rightbox` element, I'd suggest:

```
$('img').click(
    function(){
        var that = $(this);
        if (that.attr('src').indexOf('thumb')>-1){
            $('#rightbox img').hide();
            $('#rightbox img').eq(that.index()).show();
            /* or:
            var newSrc = that.attr('src').replace('thumb','large');
            $('img[src="' + newSrc + '"]').show();
            */
        }
    });
```

However, if they're present in the DOM, but not in the `#rightbox`:

```
$('img').click(
    function(){
        var that = $(this);
        if (that.attr('src').indexOf('thumb')>-1){
            $('#rightbox img').empty();
            var newSrc = that.attr('src').replace('thumb','large');
            $('img[src="' + newSrc + '"]').clone().appendTo('#rightbox');
        }
    });
```

If they're not present in the DOM but must be created:

```
$('img').click(
    function(){
        var that = $(this);
        if (that.attr('src').indexOf('thumb')>-1){
            $('#rightbox img').empty();
            var newSrc = that.attr('src').replace('thumb','large'),
                newImg = $('<img />',{src : newSrc}).appendTo('#rightbox');
        }
    });
```

References:

1. jQuery:

   - [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
   - [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
   - [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).
   - [`empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/).
   - [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
   - [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
   - [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).
2. 'Plain' JavaScript

   - [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
   - [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: +1 I see your still editing, but you on the right track with this one. BTW, the larger images go into the `<div id="rightbox"></div>`

Comment: Ah; thank you! I saw that, I think, but didn't pay enough attention. Sigh... =)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("img").click(function(){
    var largesrc = $(this).attr("src").replace("thumb","large");
    $("#rightbox").html('<img src="'+largesrc+'" width="560" height="297" class="largeimage" />');
});
```

When an img is clicked, this function will get the image src, replace the folder thumb to large, and then place this as an image with that src in the rightbox div. This will do it for all images on your page so you might want to give the smaller pictures a class of 'smallimage' or similar then change the first line to `$(".smallimage").click(function(){`

Answer (score 0):

Would this be helpful? By just changeing the given width which will automatically change the height.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".imgtopleft").click(function() {
            $(".imgtopleftlargerimage").css("width","1000");
        });
});
```

Comment: Except of the forgotten 'px' behind the '1000' your script is not optimized

Answer (score 0):

I would go with this as the source code, and then hijack the click event on the link.

```
<a href="group1/large/01.png" class="viewLargeImage">
   <img src="group1/thumb/01.png" width="160" height="97" class="imgtopleft" />
</a>
```

With this JavaScript:

```
$('.viewLargeImage').click( function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var bigPath = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).replaceWith( "<img src=" + bigPath + " />" );
});
```

If the need to show up in the rightbox:

```
$('.viewLargeImage').click( function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var bigPath = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#rightbox').html( "<img src=" + bigPath + " />" );
});
```

Then google can index the big pictures, and people without javascript can find them to.